# Retrieve Azure load balancer NAT port for Azure VM in C#

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-load-balancer

I have an Azure Load Balancer in front of a Azure VM Scale Set (VMSS). I also have a NAT pool configured on the Load Balancer like the following:

`{
            "name": "InstanceInputEndpointNatPool",
            "properties": {
              "backendPort": 10000,
              "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('loadBalancers_01_name')), '/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerIPConfig')]"
              },
              "frontendPortRangeStart": 10100,
              "frontendPortRangeEnd": 10500,
              "protocol": "Tcp"
            }
          }`

Essentially, for each VM in the VMSS, the load balancer forwards a request received at DNSName:PORT(between 10100-10500) to one of the VMs:10000(same backend port).

Is it possible to retrieve the PORT assigned to this VM, programmatically in C#, for a program running on that VM? This would help me directly target that VM port.

Answer (score -1):

You may refer the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/network-dotnet-manage-internal-load-balancers/) and find the code on [GitHub link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/network-dotnet-manage-internal-load-balancers/blob/master/Program.cs).