# Inbound NAT Pool, how to discover external port?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-load-balancer

**Background**: If i understand correctly InboundNATPools are used to map a range of external ports each to a specific VM on a VMSS behind a LB.
e.g. `{LB_IP:p1,LB_IP:p2, ...} => {VM1:p0,VM2:p0, ...}`

**Question**: How can a VM (i.e. app) discover it's assigned ***external*** port? 
e.g. in the example above the right port from `{p1,p2,..}`

**A possible approach**: i'm considering using an external service which'll listen for connections on a well known port and when a connection is established respond with the source port.
I'm reluctant to use it since it means maintaining another service.

**Extra details**:
i'm running on Service Fabric and the protocol for the port is TCP.

**Identical unanswered question**:
[Retrieve Azure load balancer NAT port for Azure VM in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298789/retrieve-azure-load-balancer-nat-port-for-azure-vm-in-c-sharp)
 didn't get a valid answer, i hope to resurface the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming your scaleset IDs are contiguous, you could use

`curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-12-01"`

which will give you the nodename in the format of `nodename_0`

adding the number after the _ to the start port of the load balancer *should* give you the port

Its very hacky, and I really hope there is a better solution!

Personally I preferred to provide VPN access, so that those ports could be accessed directly from the internal VNET

Comment: the name can also be retrieved in service using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Fabric_NodeName") but i'd prefer a less hacky solution - thanks!